ADO object don't work in Classic ASP page
I have to use the classic asp to access a database, but when the connection object is created, something happens that interrupts the execution of the script without giving an error. Can you give me some advice? Thank you.
<%
    On Error Resume Next

    Class ImmobiliADO       
        Private m_DbConn
        Private strConn
        Private cmd
        Private Rs
        Private SQL

        Public Function open_Connection()
            'Set m_DbConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
            Set m_DbConn = new ADODB.Connection
            
            strConn = "DSN=DSN_MySQL;" & "User=root;" & "Password=root;"
            m_DbConn.Open strConn

            If m_DbConn.Errors.Count > 0 Then
                Response.write "Connection error: #" & m_DbConn.Errors.Item(0)
                m_DbConn.Errors.Clear

                open_Connection = Nothing
            Else
                open_Connection = m_DbConn
            End If
            
        End Function        

        '...

    End Class

    Dim immobili_ADO
    Set immobili_ADO = New ImmobiliADO

    Dim test
    Set test = immobili_ADO.open_Connection()    
    Response.write "Connesso al db..." & test.State      
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "Error: " & Err.Number
        WScript.Echo "Source: " &  Err.Source
        WScript.Echo "Description: " &  Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If    
    
%>


Using Windows 10 I installed the mdac library but nothing changed.

There's no error because On Error Resume Next hides it, comment out that line and try again to see what the error is.

Installed the 32bit driver and now the error is: Object required: '[string: "Provider=MSDASQL.1;"]'

When instantiating COM objects like ADODB you need to use the Server.CreateObject() method and pass the correct progid in this case ADODB.Connection the New statement is only supported by user-defined classes in VBScript. See Remarks section under Class Object.

Yes, I had already corrected it with Server.CreateObject(). But now apparently, from the error specified above, i discovered that ADO requires an OLE provider but doesn't exist for MySql. Is that correct?

Would check with connectionstrings.com.

Yes, now with the connection strings linked in the similar discussion the connection object is created but the recordset count is -1.

You can better uncomment this line (because it may work)
Set m_DbConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
and remove this one: (because it does not work)
Set m_DbConn = new ADODB.Connection
